# (Python Basic) more elegant way of creating a dictionary

Tags: python

Is there a more elegant way to write a code like this?

```
my_dic = {
    'Model':['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Melon', 'Orange', 'Grape'], 
    'AAA':[
        method1(y, y_Apple), 
        method1(y, y_Banana), 
        method1(y, y_Pineapple), 
        method1(y, y_Melon),
        method1(y, y_Orange),
        method1(y, y_Grape)]
    ,'BBB':[
        method2(y, y_Apple), 
        method2(y, y_Banana), 
        method2(y, y_Pineapple), 
        method2(y, y_Melon),
        method2(y, y_Orange),
        method2(y, y_Grape)]
    ,'CCC':[
        method3(y,y_Apple), 
        method3(y, y_Banana), 
        method3(y, y_Pineapple), 
        method3(y, y_Melon),
        method3(y, y_Orange),
        method3(y, y_Grape)]
    ,'DDD':[
        method4(y, y_Apple), 
        method4(y, y_Banana), 
        method4(y, y_Pineapple), 
        method4(y, y_Melon),
        method4(y, y_Orange),
        method4(y, y_Grape)]
    ,'EEE':[
        method5(y, y_Apple), 
        method5(y, y_Banana), 
        method5(y, y_Pineapple), 
        method5(y, y_Melon),
        method5(y, y_Orange),
        method5(y, y_Grape)]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
my_dic = dict()

my_dic['Model'] = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Pineapple', 'Melon', 'Orange', 'Grape']
y_list = [y_Apple, y_Banana, y_Pineapple, y_Melon, y_Orange, y_Grape]
keys = zip(['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE'], ['method1', 'method2', 'method3', 'method4', 'method5'])
func  = lambda F, a, b: eval(F)(a,b)

for name, method in keys:
    my_dic[name] = [ func(method, y, y2) for y2 in y_list]
```

Comment: This works perfectly well. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no more elegant way of doing this; it's a matter of trade-off between readability and code size you need. 
@aminrd provided a very efficient implementation in terms of code size, but less readable to human.

Also this is not the right forum for this question.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie here in StackExchange. I was working on my data science project with Python, that's why I thought I could post my question here. Thanks for your comment, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do:

```
model = { # use OrderedDict if you're on python 3.6 or older to preserve ordering
    'Apple': y_Apple,
    'Banana': y_Banana,
    'Pineapple': y_Pineapple,
    'Melon': y_Melon,
    'Orange': y_Orange,
    'Grape': y_Grape,
}

methods = {
    'AAA': method1,
    'BBB': method2,
    'CCC': method3, 
    'DDD': method4,
    'EEE': method5,
} 

my_dic = {
    'Model': list(model.keys()),
    **{k: {meth(y, y_Fruit) for y_Fruit in model.values()} for k, meth in methods.items()}
}
```

Comment: I get an error in the line **{k: {meth(y, y_Fruit) for y_Fruit in model.values()} for k, meth in methods}, and the error is: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2). It would be great if you could explain how ** works in this code.

Comment: @Hani: I've updated the code to fix the error. The ** is the [Double asterisks in dictionary literals](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) to merge dictionary into a new dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. :) Although, I got another error, which is TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I've tried with eval(meth)(y, y_Fruit), but then the result is not what I intended... I also wanted to convert this dictionary to DataFrame,

Comment: @Hani: don't wrap the method in quotes, and don't use eval, just pass the function object directly